# How to properly close application with exit code

Tags: c++, command-line, initialization, wxwidgets, exit-code

In my wxWidgets application I am checking for a command line arguement, and if I find it, I do an action then I close the window. However, I can't seem to get the application to close properly. I want to close the program with an exit code, such as 3. When I check for the command line parameter in wxApp::OnInit, I tried to just call `exit(3)`, however, this seemed to be improper as it caused memory leaks somewhere within wxwidgets.

I then tried to store the exit code, override OnRun and return there, however, when I do I get a crash in `init.cpp` line `472` on `return wxTheApp->OnRun();`.

Does anyone know how I can properly close the application with a custom exit code from wxApp after detecting the application should close? I also tried to overload `wxApp::OnExit`, however, it never ends up being called, even when I don't overload `OnRun`.

Code example at http://codepad.org/WYiOJq55 due to the code not being allowed in this post for some reason

**EDIT** Paste of the code:

```
int SomeApplication::OnRun()
{
    if(mExitCode != 0)
    {
        ExitMainLoop();
        return mExitCode;
    }
    else
        return wxApp::OnRun();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps show a simple self contained example of the behavior in question?

Comment: `exit` doesn't allow the stack to unwind, so obviously any object with a non-trivial destructor will "leak".

Comment: I have been trying, but I keep getting errors saying my code is not formatted, even though it is

Comment: As a sidenote, in C++11 you can call `std::terminate` and friends instead of `exit`

Comment: rubenvb: Do you happen to know of a way to do this with wxWidgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your comments it seems that you do not ever launch a wxFrame and want to just exit an application as soon as possible. To do this, have your constructor for `SomeApplication` initialize `mExitCode` to `0`. Then during `OnInit` do your command line argument check, and if you want to close your application immediantly after the check, set `mExitCode` to your exit code and `return true` from `OnInit`.

The following is how your `OnRun` function would work without ever opening another window.

```
int SomeApplication::OnRun()
{
    if(mExitCode == 0)
        wxApp::OnRun();

    return mExitCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I override wxAPP::OnRun() like this:

```
int MyApp::OnRun()
{
    wxApp::OnRun();
    return 3;
}
```

Everything works just fine

If I create a little batch file

```
minimal.exe
echo el is %ERRORLEVEL%
```

it produces the expected result

```
>test.bat

>minimal.exe

>echo el is 3
el is 3
```

I think the problem with your code

```
int SomeApplication::OnRun()
{
    if(mExitCode != 0)
    {
        ExitMainLoop();
        return mExitCode;
    }
    else
        return wxApp::OnRun();
}
```

is that you are not calling the base class OnRun BEFORE checking your exit code, presumably set somewhere in the code executed by wxAPP::OnRun()

So I am guessing this will work for you

```
int SomeApplication::OnRun()
{
    wxApp::OnRun();
    return mExitCode;
 }
```

Comment: It seems as with running the function like that, the program will not actually close. While that function does get called, the return is never called as it seems to just be in wxApp::OnRun

Comment: What function?  Running like what?  I do not really understand you comment.  When the last window is closed, wxApp:onRun returns.  When  SomeApplication::OnRun returns, the return value is passed to exit().  ... Have you tried the code I suggested?

Comment: Running your OnRun function will never hit the return because since I am doing a command line check, I never open a window. I only open a window after the command line check if I do not wish to have the application to close based upon the parameters provided.